# Efficient way to write a fallback for oklch color spectrum

Tags: css, colors

He all,

Is there an efficient way to write a fallback for the oklch color function? Say I have the following css:

```
color: oklch(95%, 0.2, 0);
```

Is there a build tool or some other way to create a fallback so that the css will look something like this:

```
color: #ffb0e9;
color: oklch(95%, 0.2, 0);
```

Comment: I think not, probably because of [W3: 17. Sample code for Color Conversions](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color/#sample)

Comment: @RenevanderLende It is done here: https://products.aspose.app/svg/color-converter/oklch-to-hex, so I believe it should be possible. But I can't figure out from the source code of the website how it is done.

Comment: From looking at the functions from the color conversions it looks like this is possible, OKLCH -> OKLAB -> XYZ -> rgb. Looks fun wil give it a shot someday

Comment: I actually meant that there probably is no *efficient* tool. Your example seems most efficient, maybe combined with CSS *custom properties* (something like `color: var(--clr-okl, var(--clr-hex))` if `--clr-okl` is undefined/`unset` then it falls back to `--clr-hex`), but that's about it without JS conversion tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your project is using / able to use [PostCSS](https://postcss.org/) (perhaps with [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/)), then I might recommend the @csstools/postcss-oklab-function PostCSS plugin:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@csstools/postcss-oklab-function

I have not tested how this works with custom properties, but the behavior would be effectively as you described for your example code:

```
color: rgb(255, 231, 238);
color: oklch(95% 0.2 0);
```

According to the plugin documentation, the fallback color seems like it would be RGB, not hexadecimal, but that shouldn't matter for your case.